# Separate clock process from sidekiq workers on Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, containers, sidekiq, clockwork

I am currently working on moving my environment off Heroku and part of my application is runs a clock process that sets off a Sidekiq background job.

As I understand it, Sidekiq is composed of a client, which sends jobs off to be queued into Redis and a server which pulls off requests of the queue and processes them. I am now trying to split out my application into the following containers on Docker:
- Redis container
- Clock container (Using Clockwork gem)
- Worker container
- Web application container (Rails)

However, I am not sure how one is supposed to split up this Sidekiq server and client. Essentially, the clock container needs to be running Sidekiq on it so that the client can send off jobs to the Redis queue every so often. However, the worker containers should also run Sidekiq (the server though) on them so that they can process the jobs. I assume that splitting up the responsibilities between different containers should be quite possible to do since Heroku allows you to split this across various dynos.

I can imagine one way to do this would be to assign the clock container to pull off a non-existent queue so that it just never pulls any jobs off the queue and then set the worker to be pulling off a queue that exists. However, this just doesn't seem like the most optimal approach to me since it will still be checking for new jobs in this non-existing queue.

Any tips or guides on how I can start going about this?

Answer (score 0):

The sidekiq client just publishes jobs into redis. A sidekiq deamon process just subscribes to redis and starts worker threads as they are published.

So you can just install the redis gem on both conatainers: `Clock container`  and  `Worker Container`  and start the worker daemon  only on the `Worker Container` and provide a proper [redis config](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis) to both. You also have to make sure that the worker sourcecode is available on both servers/containers as Sidekiq client just stores the name of the worker class and then the daemon instanciates it through metaprogramming.

But actually you also can just include a sidekiq daemon process together with every application wich needs to process a worker job. Yes, there is this best practise of docker for one container per process, however imho this is not an all or nothing rule. In this case i see both processes as one unity. It's just a way of running some code in background. You then would just configure that instances of same applications just work against same sidekiq queues. Or you could even configure that every physical node runs again a separate queue.